# Package questionr

Tags: r

keep receiving the message below when running this: `library("questionr")`

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘questionr’:  package
>   ‘promises’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it
>   needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Did you try doing what message suggested?

Comment: Thank you. unable to do it because i don't understand what is asked

Comment: `install.packages('promises')`.

Comment: Great. Problem solved. Thank you all